# GPS work on emulator, but not on device

Tags: android, gps

I made a application that works fine on the emulator (using telnet and geo fix), but on the device the callbacks of the LocationListener are not called at all.

I already checked permission (  on manifest.xml), checked if GPS is active (it is, and works fine in google maps, and the satellite drawing shows up when my app turns on).

Someone has any clue on what may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed related to accuracy, the GPS do not work when it is not accurate.

But manually loading Wi-Fi was failing.

The correct solution is use the **Criteria** class, and then find the "best provider" automatically based on the Criteria. It will accept bad accuracy values, also last values when more accurate, and whatnot, mimicking the behavior of the GPS on Google Maps APP.

Answer (score 1):

Did you:

(1) make a release key on your machine?

(2) get a RELEASE API key from Google based on the MD5 fingerprint generated by your release key?

(3) build that Google key into your code or xml?

(4) sign your application with the release key?

Unless you remember getting a second (release) key from the Google site, that's the problem.

***On second thoughts the GPS should still work, it's just that you wouldn't get the map***

Comment: What you are talking about? What key? LocationListener has no such function, it does?

Comment: If you want the Google maps you'll need a release API key to run on a device. All apps must be signed with either a debug key or a release one. If it's published it must be a release key see http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: But google maps DO work! I am saying that my application that does not work!

Answer (score 0):

If your program isn't calling your onLocationChange method then you probably are inside or somewhere where you can't get a GPS signal. Try moving outside somewhere with a clear view of the sky.

Which methods have you defined in your location listener? Because the onProviderDisabled and onProiderEnabled functions should work even without a GPS signal.

Comment: Indeed, you are sorta correct. I tested it some minutes ago on a Galaxy Tab, and its logcat wrote that accuracy was bigger than 50 meters (where I am, it is 60), and thus onLocationChange was ignored.

Comment: GPS accuracy depends on how many satellites are in view (as well as imperfect orbit files, upper atmosphiric weather, and other things you can't easily correct). For greater accuracy move somewhere you have a clear view of the entire sky. You shouldn't expect accuracy much better than 5 meters or so, even with 9-10 sats in view. There's a great free app called GPS Status that tells you where each satellite is in the sky and if the phone is receiving the signal.

Comment: Not that... I mean how I increase accuracy mask. The app works fine even with a 150 meters error.

Comment: If the gps is able to calculate a position it will call onLocationChanged regardless of accuracy. Maybe you should look into network_provider instead of GPS_PROVIDER if you don't need much accuracy.

Comment: Then what is the issue? It works for now only on the emulator... On a nokia, nothing happen (and onLocationChanged is never called) on Sansumg I get this message

Comment: 04-20 16:10:53.409: DEBUG/gps_BRCM(2521): on_location_cb() : lat(0.000000), lon(0.000000), flags(0x00000000), accuracy(1500.000000)
04-20 16:10:53.409: DEBUG/gps_BRCM(2521): on_location_cb() : accuracy is 50 over than 0, drop..

Comment: For the nokia phone: When you run your app there should be a GPS symbol at the top of the screen. If the bars are flashing then the GPS can't receive a signal and you need to move outdoors. For the

Comment: I am not sure what is happening with the Samsung error message. I have never seen that before. I'm sorry. What API are you developing in?